# MongoDB find and remove - the fastest way

Tags: performance, mongodb

I have a quick question, what is the fast way to grab and delete an object from a mongo collection. Here is the code, I have currently:

```
$cursor = $coll->find()->sort(array('created' => 1))->limit(1);
$obj = $cursor->getNext();
$coll->remove(array('name' => $obj['name']));
```

as you can see above it grabs one document from the database and deletes it (so it isn't processed again). However fast this may be, I need it to perform faster. The challenge is that we have multiple processes doing this and processing what they have found BUT sometimes two or more of the processes grab the same document therefore making duplicates. Basically I need to make it so a document can only be grabbed once. So any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Peter,
It's hard to say what the best solution is here without understanding all the context - but one approach which you could use is `findAndModify`. This will query for a single document and return it, and also apply an update to it.

You could use this to find a document to process and simultaneously modify a "status" field to mark it as being processed, so that other workers can recognize it as such and ignore it.

There is an example here that may be useful:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/

Comment: this is exactly what I need. Thanks a ton man. Just curious but how would this command look in PHP? I am currently looking into this but if you could give me an example that would be great. If I find out how first, I will post the code for everyone to see.

Comment: $db->command(array('findandmodify' => 'CollectionName', 'sort' => array('created' => 1),'limit' => 1, 'remove' => true));

Answer (score 8):

Use the findAndRemove function as documented here:
http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html

The findAndRemove function retrieve and object from the mongo database and delete it in a single (atomic) operation.

findAndRemove(query, sort[, options], callback)

- The query object is used to retrieve the object from the database (see collection.find())
- The sort parameter is used to sort the results (in case many where found)

Comment: That link might hold the answer but please add the relevant details from that link to your answer. Links do break.

Comment: It seems that in MongoDB 3 java API findAndRemove has been replaced by findOneAndDelete() `TDocument findOneAndDelete(Bson filter, FindOneAndDeleteOptions options);`

Answer (score 3):

I make a new answer to remark the fact:

As commented by @[peterscodeproblems](https://stackoverflow.com/users/943749/peterscodeproblems) in the accepted answer. The native way to this in mongodb right now is to use the

```
findAndModify(query=<document>, remove=True)
```

As pointed out by the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#sort-and-remove).

As it is native, and atomic, I expect this to be the faster way to do this.

Answer (score -4):

I am new to `mongodb` and not entirely sure what your query is trying to do, but here is how I would do it

```
# suppose database is staging
# suppose collection is data
use staging
db.data.remove(<your_query_criteria>)
```

where  is a map and can contain any search criteria you want

Not sure if this would help you.