# C# MongoDB, remove top 10 from sorted collection

Tags: c#, mongodb, database

I have a collection with 1000 items. I want to sort them per date (SaveDateUtc field) and remove the top 10 of them, so I'm left with the 990 newest items in my collection.

I could do a Find and then a Remove, no problem, but it'd be much better if I could do this with just a Remove call. But I can't find a way to sort and set top 10 through the query.

So my question is, can I do this in just one call?
(I'm using the C# driver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there was similar question: [MongoDB find and remove - the fastest way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539575/mongodb-find-and-remove-the-fastest-way)

But unfortunately `findAndUpdate` cannot be restricted by records number. So my propositions to you:

- You may introduce some surrogate field so you could use it as field in query
- You may write you own java-script server-side function that will do this operation on server side. Benefits - operation is done on server, it is atomic. Pitfall - it is not works with sharded tables.